# Scrollview becomes visible even when it's parents' visibility is set to GONE

Tags: android, scrollview, visibility, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have this strange problem where a ScrollView that belongs to a LinearLayout with visibility set to GONE all of a sudden becomes visible on the screen. The problem only manifests itself on Jellybean 4.1.1, not on Android 2.3. It seems to happen mostly when switching the parent LinearLayout's visibility from GONE to VISIBLE and back to GONE quickly (like in 1-2 seconds).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I have come up with so far is to set visibility GONE/VISIBLE on the ScrollView as well as it's parent LinearLayout. This completely solved the problem for me on Jellybean 4.1.1.